# Python - Compare 2 csv files, write the last column of matching row to 3rd file

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 csv files:

File1.csv

```
param.1, 256,254,236
param.2, 256,260,300
param.3, 300,700,800
...
```

File2.csv

```
1,300,700,800,0.8
2,256,254,236,0.85
3,256,260,300,0.9
...
```

As you can see the order of the rows are not similar. file2.csv has an extra row which is the result. I want the script to go through and compare each one of the row with file1.csv, find the matching row. Then take the last value from the matched row (0.8) and take the index value from file1.csv (param.3). then output a a new file with the name result.3 and have 0.8 written in that file. Likewise I want to do this for several hundreds of data. And if that last field is blank I want to output "none", with the respective file name result.x

Please let me know if I'm not clear. Thanks for your help.

Sorry I should have added what I am trying so far, this does not give me any output. Not sure what is wrong

```
noDesignVariables = 4 # ---- change this to proper input
with open('/home/prabh00b/dakoat_wb_script/exp1.csv', 'r') as fin:  # add proper location index for exp1.csv
    for line in fin.readlines():
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        index = int(line[0])
#        print line
#        print index

        if len(line) == noDesignVariables + 1:
            res = float(line[noDesignVariables + 1])
            print res
        else:
            res = 'none'

with open('result.out.%d' %index, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(str(res) + '\n')
```

Comment: Do you mean rows or columns?  Also, please show us what you've attempted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Construct two dictionaries containing your data, then merge them on common keys

```
>>> d1 = {(b.strip(),c,d):a for a,b,c,d in[r.split(',')for r in open('f1.csv')]}
>>> d2 = {(b,c,d):[a,e] for a,b,c,d,e in[r.split(',')for r in open('f2.csv')]}
>>> d3 = {k2:d2[k2]+[d1[k2]] for k2 in d2 if k2 in d1}
```

The result is like

```
>>> print d3
{('256', '254', '236'): ['2', '0.85', 'param.1'],
 ('256', '260', '300'): ['3', '0.9', 'param.2'],
 ('300', '700', '800'): ['1', '0.8', 'param.3']}
```

When you have `d3` you can output everything you want (I have to admit that I've not fully understood your output requirements...).